# Xamarin Android Activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am able to press the back button to from `LAYOUT2` back to `LAYOUT1`.
But how would I go from `LAYOUT3` to `LAYOUT2` to `LAYOUT1`?

I have tried doing different things such as this

In the `MainActivity` I have this

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    StartActivity(intent);

}
```

In the SecondActivity I have this

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{

        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Menu));
        StartActivity(intent);

}
```

With that code above it just stays on the `SecondActivity` and doesn't go back to the `MainActivity` - why?

Comment: You shouldn't have your back launching new intents, you should have it close the current intent. Then it will automatically go back to the previous one.

Comment: Please refer to : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: you can use Finish() method to remove the current activity

Answer (score 0):

By default app behaviour is simply go to last activity.
you can try without any extra coding.

I think nothing will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your overrides for the `OnBackPressed` and the behaviour you're expecting will be achieved.